# CSS - gradient set for IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

How do I set gradient for IE, because I was trying but without any luck, I got it working on chrome, firefox, opera but not in IE

```
html, body {  
    height: 100%;  
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BDE25E 0%, #8BB31D 100%);  
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BDE25E 0%, #8BB31D 100%);  
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #BDE25E 0%, #8BB31D 100%);  
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #BDE25E), color-stop(1, #8BB31D));  
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BDE25E 0%, #8BB31D 100%);  
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #BDE25E 0%, #8BB31D 100%);  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    background-attachment: fixed;  
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;   
    color:#FFFFFF;   
    font-size:11px;   
}
```

But when I launch it in IE, I get white background instead of green gradient.

Comment: Try this generator: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no code in there that IE supports. Use [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to create cross-browser gradients:

```
background: #bde25e; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bde25e 2%, #8bb31d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(2%,#bde25e), color-stop(100%,#8bb31d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bde25e 2%,#8bb31d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bde25e 2%,#8bb31d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bde25e 2%,#8bb31d 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bde25e 2%,#8bb31d 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bde25e', endColorstr='#8bb31d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: thank you, but when I uplead it on my website and I scroll down, in IE it changes backgroud gradient why??  http://lipcik.isdevelop.sk/SRS_web/

Comment: @Mario LIPCIK Make a div and style the position as fixed,

Comment: @itsme No need to do that. Use [`background-attachment:fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-attachment) (supported in IE4+).

Comment: @Rob W I thought about it, but I wasn't pretty sure that it works well on all browser

Comment: @RobW I did use it but it is still same

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this in IE,

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#BDE25E ', endColorstr='#8BB31D ');
```