# CSS gradients for all web browsers

Tags: asp.net, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS - gradient set for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298053/css-gradient-set-for-ie)

I set a style for li tag and hover

```
.centermenu li
{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 32px;
    width: 152px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

    .centermenu li:hover, .centermenu li:focus
    {
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255,255,255,.2)), to(rgba(255,255,255,0)));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2), rgba(255,255,255,0));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2), rgba(255,255,255,0));
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2), rgba(255,255,255,0));
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2), rgba(255,255,255,0));
        background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2), rgba(255,255,255,0));
         }
```

It is set in Firefox and GoogleChrom but don't in Internet Explorer.

I set this code for IE but don't set style.

```
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF 20%', endColorstr='#ffffff 1%');
  /* For Internet Explorer 8 */
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF 20%', endColorstr='#ffffff 1%')";
```

Comment: internet expolorer does not supports this, atleast ie8 and earlier to this

Comment: filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000');

Comment: I use IE9 and IE10 but don't work.

Comment: @skhurams: Thanks a lot, but how to convert `rgba(255,255,255,.2)` to Colorstr?

Comment: you can convert using online tools like http://www.colorpicker.com/

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt work in older browsers (if i remember good it's from css3 specification).

to have it working on more browsers u can use svg background but it's not the best way too.